# Firebase cloud functions deployment error "Invalid source token"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

While running a a deployment for firebase cloud functions, I got this error
`Invalid source token`.
There seems to be no documentation anywhere about the cause or fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once experienced this error before.
Re-running the deployments seems to fix the issue.